# Editor that can collapse values/brackets for OSX in BIG JSON files (100MB+)

Tags: osx, json, editor

I'm working with ElasticSearch now which sometimes can throw 40MB JSONs back at me. Just browsing such a thing is difficult without support for collapsing/expanding some JSON subtrees (in brackets in JSON of course) and I need to edit this on top of browsing.

Is there an editor or at least viewer for OSX that is capable of doing that?

Unfortunately SublimeText 3 is not able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim editor. See: [How to fold text in a JSON file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10562/467)

As per above, the minimal setup would be:

```
:set filetype=json
:syntax on
:set fdm=syntax
```

Then use `zo` and `zc` shortcuts to open and close foldings (see: `:h fold-commands`).

See also: [Folding at Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding).

For better JSON highlighting of keywords vs values, you can consider [vim-json](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json) plugin.

To improve performance further more for a big file, try to open it in read-only (`-R`).